# How to prevent onBlur for a sibling or related component events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am implementing a complex autocomplete functionality, and the point is that when the input gets focused, I should show the result box, and when the user goes to the next input or clicks anywhere on the screen, or presses Escape, then I should close the result box.

To close the result box, I'm using the `onBlur` event.

The problem is that inside the result box I have a button that takes the user to a more complete search dialog, but when I click it, the `onBlur` event is fired and prevents the click of this button to happen.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input 
          onBlur={() => setIsOpen(false)} 
          onFocus={() => setIsOpen(true)} 
      />

      {isOpen && (
        <div>
          something
          <br />
          <button 
              onClick={() => setText("i am clicked")}>click me</button>
        </div>
      )}
      <br />
      <input />
      <br />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I make it work properly?

You can see a live example in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-snowflake-88gl1e?file=/pages/index.js:0-510)

I'm using Next.js

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to group `input` and `button` to have a wider focusing area. I'm using `div` for that purpose, but `onBlur` and `onFocus` are not applied for a usual `div`, so we need to have `tabIndex="1"` which is to make that element interactive with those events.

```
<div
  tabIndex="1"
  onBlur={() => setIsOpen(false)}
  onFocus={() => setIsOpen(true)}
>
</div>
```

Secondly, we should use `onMouseDown` event instead of `onClick`, which is to avoid focusing state on the `button` element.

```
<button onMouseDown={() => setText("i am clicked")}>
    click me
</button>
```

The full implementation can be (https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-violet-z0u3jr)

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        tabIndex="1"
        onBlur={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        onFocus={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      >
        <input />
        {isOpen && (
          <div>
            something
            <br />
            <button onMouseDown={() => setText("i am clicked")}>
              click me
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
      <br />
      <input />
      <br />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```